# Change albedo from Material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[I need to change the albedo of the Unity C # Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQVSr.png)

```
public Material material;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    material = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;
    material.color = Color.red;
}
```

This is the code I wrote, however, the color of Albedo is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's important to know what shader is being used for the material in question.  I'll assume you're working with the Unity Standard shader.

In most cases what you have would work with the standard shader.  An alternative to try is
`material.SetColor("_Color", newColor);`

"_Color" is the name of the property found in the shader.  After the code executes, check the material in the inspector for your color change.  If there's no change, your chosen shader likely doesn't apply color the way you want and you should try an alternative.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way OP is changing the albedo color.Your solution is just another way to do it but OP's code is fine.

Comment: Not working .. :(

  material = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;
  material.SetColor ("_Color", Color.red);
  Debug.Log(material.GetColor("_Color"));